# Passing data between master and content pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

This is my task . I have to create a master page and its two child pages. Details are below

- Declare 3 session variables in master page.

  - Pages_viewed
  - ChildAppData1
  - ChildAppData2
- Declare 1 session variable in each child application

  - ChildVar1
  - ChildVar2
- Once the child application loads

  - Pages_viewed ++;
  - Set `ChildVar1 = ChildAppData1 = datetime.now();` or `ChildVar2 = ChildAppData2 = datetime.now();`

Add a button to the master page that resets ALL variables.

Display all 5 variables in master page as well as active child application.

I have to show the no of times a child page is visited in page_viewed variable.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to Redirect to self with some information/command in the `get` parameter to self page.

like  `Default.master` enclosing
      `Default.aspx`

```
->Redirect to

   `Default.aspx?cmd=clearAllVariables`
```

On `Page_Load` check

```
if(!PostBack && (Request["cmd"] != null) && (Request["cmd"].ToString() == "clearAllVariables")) 
{ 
  clearAllVariablesImplementation(); 
}
```

Comment: please help me with the other tasks too how should i declare session var and everything. im new to sessions

Comment: Here is how -> `Session["someVariable"] = someObject;`

Comment: i want to increment the page_viewed variable by everytime a page is visited.. can u tell me how to do this ??